# Can we use the natural logarithm to find a previous prime?

Tags: number-theory

Using any natural number $n \geq 3$ , can we set up a formula with the natural logarithm of something $x$ to find a previous prime? My calculations tell me strongly that the answer is yes, but I have not yet found what the mysterious $x$ is. Here I am using $x$ to represent the unknown. $\ln(x)$ subtracted from $n$ should be close to the greatest prime less than $n$. The completion of this formula represents the completion of many proofs as it will become part of a bigger formula.

So far, $n-\ln(n)$ seems fairly close, however I need something better.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In short, the answer is no.

It is true that the *average* gap between primes near $n$ is about $\ln n$, by the prime number theorem. But those gaps are extremely varied in size, in an unpredictable way. For example, we conjecture that the greatest prime less than $n$ will have size $n - \lambda\ln n$, where $\lambda$ is distributed like a continuous Poisson random variable of mean $1$.

The usual moral applies here: the primes are distributed too unevenly for any simple formula (involving only smooth functions found in calculus classes, for example) to be able to tell us exactly where the primes will occur.

Comment: You say, "we conjecture that the greatest prime less than $n$ will have size $n - \lambda\ln n$, where $\lambda$ is distributed like a continuous Poisson random variable of mean $1$." This includes $ln(n)$ in it, which is what I was looking for. My calculations told me that $ln(n)$ would be in the formula, but I did not know where to start. What I need to use the formula for is to find the two greatest primes less than or equal to $n$ for $n\geq 3$.